# Website javascript calculator not working, need solution

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, wordpress

I recently made my website SSL certified, but now my calculator is broken.
Url: https://secondunitcentersmc.org/calculator/

Please help provide a solution, the only affected drop down is the first location one.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keocf.png)

Console Log Error:
angular.js:12011 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://secondunitcentersmc.org/calculator/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://secondunitcentersmc.org/wp-content/themes/secondunitcenter/calc/data/rents.json'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Changing this URL to https does not work, (it causes the form to not appear) neither does changing $http to $https in both locations within the file

Image from scripts/app.js of my website. It is also a wordpress site.

Comment: The error message it pretty much telling you..  You have a request to -> `"http://secondunitcentersmc.org/wp-content/themes/secondunitcenter/calc/data/rents.json"`  It also needs to be `https` not `http`

Answer (score 0):

So When I navigate to http://secondunitcentersmc.org/wp-content/themes/secondunitcenter/calc/data/rents.json it is automatically changing to https. In your js file where you make the call to this page, does the url there start with http or https?

Instead of using a json file for this data, you might want to consider creating a private custom post type for the locations, then you can just use the standard wordpress query to call them into the drop down. It will also be easier to add and edit them in the future. (and get rid of your https/http error :))

How did you add https to your site? with a plugin or manually? If manually- you need to update your site address and wordpress address in general>settings as well as add some code to your .htaccess file. more info here (method #2) https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/